# Gevent and flask - thread local

Tags: flask, gevent

What explicit are the risks to using 'g' in flask when running a server based on Gevent?

Or are there 'none' meaning that monkey patching makes flask use greenlet local vars instead of thread locals?

Answer (score 3):

Flask supports the use of greenlets per it's documentation:

> Flask uses thread local objects (context local objects in fact, they support greenlet contexts as well) for request, session and an extra object you can put your own things on (g).

Due to this support, there is no risk in using `g` when using gevent.

Read http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/design/ for more info.